# Dirichlet Laplace Operator and its Inverse

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, linear-pde

I'm actually completely mindfucked : I have the Dirichlet Laplcian operator $(-\Delta_\mathcal{D})$ with domain $W^{2,p}(\mathbb{R}^d_+)\cap W^{1,p}_0(\mathbb{R}^d_+)$, it is not invertible but we can construct (using potential theory and good extension operators) a right and left (continuous) inverse $$(-\Delta_\mathcal{D})^{-1}:\mathrm{L}^p\longrightarrow \dot{W}^{2,p}_\mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R}^d_+)$$ where $\dot{W}^{2,p}_\mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R}^d_+)$ is the homogeneous Sobolev space with order 2 including Dirichlet Boundary Condition.

The fact is that for $u\in C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R}^d_+)$ , $$(-\Delta_\mathcal{D})^{-1} \Delta u = (-\Delta_\mathcal{D})^{-1} \Delta_\mathcal{D} u = -u$$ so it must extend as (minus) the identity on $\mathrm{L}^p(\mathbb{R}^d_+)$, but it is no longer true on $W^{2,p}(\mathbb{R}^d_+)$ (no specific Boundary condition) for $$(-\Delta_\mathcal{D})^{-1} \Delta$$ since there is no particular boundary condition.

So I have a map that is (minus) the Identity on a larger space $\mathrm{L}^p(\mathbb{R}^d_+)$ but which cannot be (minus) the identity on the subspace $W^{2,p}(\mathbb{R}^d_+)$, what the heck happened here ?

Thanks to let me know my possible mistakes.

Comment: The $L^p$ closure of $C^\infty_c$ is $L^p$. The $W^{2,p}$ closure of $C^\infty_c$ isn't $W^{2,p}$.

Comment: I know it but the equality still occurs replacing $C_c^\infty$ with $D_p(\Delta_\mathcal{D})=W^{2,p}\cap W^{1,p}_0$. Moreover one can show that the last introduced operator is bounded from $\dot{W}^{2,p}$ to $\dot{W}^{2,p}_\mathcal{D}$...

Comment: Sure, but again you're extending from a subspace with a boundary condition in a norm that "sees" the boundary condition (i.e. it is preserved by the closure operation for that norm).

Comment: Oh well ... Thanks you !